# Write a new function that returns value inputted in another function

Tags: python

```
def get_key_file():
    '''() -> file open for reading

       Return the key file.
    '''    

    return open(input("Enter the name of the key file: "), 'r')
```

I want to write another function that would return whatever the user inputted in the prompt

Comment: Can you provide an example of what this function would do? That is, what it would print and what it would return for the user input? Mark the sequence of events clearly instead of just pasting unformatted text from the python shell as in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a method that will return user input

```
def getInput():
    userInput = raw_input("Enter the name of the key file: ")

    #you can check to see if the input is valid here

    return userInput
```

This is how you call that method

```
keyFileName = getInput()
```

Comment: I need to keep the function I gave as it is, and write another function other than the one I gave that does what I have described I want it to do

Comment: @user2639519 that is what this new function does i believe

Comment: >>> getInput()
Enter the name of the key file: twins.txt
'twins.txt'

Comment: Is there a way that I get 'twins.txt' without getting the prompt?

Comment: yes, remove the string in the input() function @user2639519

Comment: show us your updated code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34660/discussion-between-stephan-and-user2639519)

Answer (score 0):

Try capturing the return value of input() in it's own variable. Then you can print the value and also use it for open. If you need to be able to use the filename elsewhere, you can return both the result of open() and the result of input(), like this:

```
def openFile():
    fileName = input("Enter the name of the key file: ")
    fileHandle = open(fileName, 'r')
    return fileName, fileHandle
```

and then use it like this:

```
name, handle = openFile()
```

python handles the return of multiple values for you.